# swipe menu for items in the recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, swipe-gesture

I need to implement a swipe menu for each items in the recyclerview.I don't want to move the cell view according to the swipe action, instead I need to reveal the swipe layout. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Try this library:

UltimateRecyclerView

https://github.com/cymcsg/UltimateRecyclerView

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.